# Change multiple button backgrounds, multiple times (Visual Studio Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, event-handling

I'm currently trying to create a seat booking system for a theatre, and I have set up 64 buttons in the arrangement of the theatre's seating plan (As shown below).
[image: Seating plan]

I have created a generic button_Click event handler, which changes the colour of the button you click on. My issue is that by using the following code, I am only able to change the colour of the buttons the first time I click it.

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;

        if(b.BackColor == Color.ForestGreen)
        {
            b.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
        }
    }
```

I understand that this will change each button to ForestGreen, then immediately back to LightSkyBlue (which it does) when I click a button, however I want it to alternate between the two colours every time I click a button. I can't seem to find a way around this.

Comment: You mean like blinking at an interval, or just a toggle between two colors?

Comment: No, I'd like for the colour to stay green (to show that the seat clicked has been selected) unless they click on it again to deselect it (turn it back to blue)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if(b.BackColor == Color.LightSkyBlue)
    {
    b.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
    }
    else
    {
        b.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
    }
}
```